# What is the proper way to update a listfield of embedded documents in mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongoengine

I am trying to define methods for performing checks and updates to a listfield of embedded documents in mongoengine. What is the proper way of doing what I'm trying to do. The code is below.

```
class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    created = DateTimeField()
    text = StringField()

class Post(Document):
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))

    def check_comment(self, comment):
        for existing_comment in self.comments:
            if comment.created == existing_comment.created and 
                comment.text == existing_comment.text:
                return True
        return False

    def add_or_replace_comment(self, comment):
        for existing_comment in self.comments:
            if comment.created == existing_comment.created:
                # how do I replace?

        # how do I add?
```

Is this even the correct way to go about something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the index of the existing comment.

You can then overwrite the old comment with the new comment (where **i** is the index) eg:

```
post.comments[i] = new_comment
```

then just do a `post.save()` and mongoengine will convert that to a `$set` operation.

Alternatively, you could just write the `$set` eg:

```
Post.objects(pk=post.pk).update(set__comments__i=comment)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an EmbeddedDocumentListField instead of a list of embedded documents. That way you get access to some [handy methods](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.base.datastructures.EmbeddedDocumentList) like *filter*, *create* or *update*:

```
class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    created = DateTimeField()
    text = StringField()

class Post(Document):
    comments = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Comment)

    ...

    def add_or_replace_comment(self, comment):
        existing = self.comments.filter(created=comment.created)
        if existing.count() == 0:
             self.comments.create(comment)
        else:
             existing.update(comment)
```

(code not tested)

Comment: note update takes keyword arguments so comment must be a dictionary of key value pairs that you unpack `existing.update(**comment)`