# Save/update a form to an EmbeddedDocument

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

Here is a simple scenario: I have a blog post with comments attach to it. Now I want to use mongoforms to let user submit their comments. Therefore I have this *models.py*:

```
class Post(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=60)
    body = StringField()
    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Comment'))

class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    author = StringField(max_length=60)
    body = StringField()
    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

And I'm using [django-mongoforms](https://github.com/stephrdev/django-mongoforms) to support the similar ModelForm functionality, within *forms.py*:

```
class CommentForm(MongoForm):
    class Meta:
        document = Comment
        fields = ('author', 'body')
```

In the *views.py*, I just want to save what user has entered, more specifically the Author and Body fields of a comment, here is the method to add a comment:

```
def add_comment(request, id):
    post = Post.objects.with_id(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=post.comments)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

Then once I click Submit button here comes the error message:

> instance must be a mongoengine document, not BaseList

So questions are:

1. How to covert BaseList to Document in MongoEngine? I have looked through the document without a hint.
2. What's the best practices here generally to handle the EmbeddedDocument? Will ReferenceDocument help?

Also there is a related questions here but without an answer:
[What is the proper way to update a listfield of embedded documents in mongoengine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279355/what-is-the-proper-way-to-update-a-listfield-of-embedded-documents-in-mongoengin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments are embedded you'll need to find and update the existing comment in the post object.  You can then overwrite the old comment with the new comment (where **i** is the index) eg:

```
post.comments[i] = new_comment
```

then just do a `post.save()` and mongoengine will convert that to a `$set` operation.

Alternatively, you could just write the `$set` directly eg:

```
Post.objects(pk=post.pk).update(set__comments__i=comment)
```

**Forms.py**

I still use the forms.py but I would pass `commit=False` to `save` that will return the comment - then append to the post and save the post like so:

```
def add_comment(request, id):
    post = Post.objects.with_id(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            post.comments.append(comment)
            post.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you for the warm help on both freenode and here all the way long.